# Use an exported CCK content type in an install schema of a module

Tags: php, drupal, cck

I have a content type built by CCK in Drupal 6. If I export it, I get a php code. How can use this code in my module's hook_install, to have this content types imported when the module is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Programatic CCK Now Possible!](http://groups.drupal.org/node/5272#comment-98128)

Also see other comments there...

Answer (score 2):

Check out the modules called [features](http://drupal.org/project/features), this out of the box gives you the ability to create modules that can contain entire CCK definitions. Very easy, and little to no custom coding is required

Comment: But with that, I would have a features dependency, am I right?

Comment: Nope, features just automates the creation of your custom module. Saves any coding by hand. Give it a go ;)

Comment: As far as I know, you can't rid of the features dependency, if you export your content types as features. Apart from that, that seems to be a very simple and easy solution indeed, thanks for your answer too!